# Getting null while loading resources in executable jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, executable

I have a desktop based maven project in which on many places i am loading images from resource folder like this:

```
JLabel Footer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/gloBOT_logo.png")));
```

`Images` folder is inside `src/main/resources`

This code works perfectly fine in eclipse IDE, but when i run my executable jar, i get `NullPointerException`, as it is not able to load the images.

Can anyone please suggest how can I load images from resource folder both in Eclipse IDE and it should work by executable jar also?

Answer (score 0):

You can try  adding `/` in front of url.

```
ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Images/gloBOT_logo.png")));
```

Comment: Do images exist in your jar file?

Comment: yes they are, and images are also in the classes folder created by maven

Answer (score 0):

Names are case sensitive, obviously, and you may want to add a / to the beginning. If that still doesn't work, make sure the file is on the right place (I think it should be project/build/classes/Images/* )

Comment: Hi, i tried yes file is on the right place, but its still not working while running jar..:(

Answer (score 0):

Somthing you can do is to use something like this:

```java
ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

BufferedImage buffLogo = null;
try {
    buffLogo = ImageIO.read( currentClassLoader.getResourceAsStream( "src/main/resources/Images/gloBOT_logo.png" ) );
}catch ( IOException ex ) {
    //exception catching and handling goes here.
}

JLabel Footer = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( buffLogo ) );
```

There is a big difference between loading resources with Class and ClassLoader, I don't know very well how to explaing that, but I hope this helps.